# Dagger (not Android) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dagger/internal/Preconditions

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, dagger, internals, preconditions

Using Dagger in raw Java and have this issue when I try running my code:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dagger/internal/Preconditions`

I am using ANT for compiling (have no other choice). Here is my dependencies I setup for Dagger:

```
        <pathelement location="${lib}/dagger-compiler-2.24.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/dagger-2.24.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/javax.inject-1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/guava-27.1-jre.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/checker-compat-qual-2.5.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/dagger-producers-2.24.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/dagger-spi-2.24.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/google-java-format-1.5.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/incap-0.2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/javapoet-1.11.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib}/jsr250-api-1.0.jar"/>
```

Does anyone know how to remedy this? All solutions I've seen across the internet are Android based, which doesn't help me.